# Getting Autoprefixer to Work with TailwindCSS and Gridsome

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, autoprefixer, tailwind-css, gridsome

I have successfully set up TailwindCSS on Gridsome by following these instructions:  https://gridsome.org/docs/assets-css/#tailwind

However, those instructions do not mention how to also set up autoprefixer.  So, I gave it a try on my own -- as follows:

- npm install autoprefixer
- Modified the `gridsome.config.js` file (see below for modified code with comments of what I changed)
- Ran `gridsome develop`
- Added the class of `flex` to a `p` to see whether or not there are any vendor prefixes added.

The result...

Nothing.  No prefixes (just `display: flex;`).

Any idea how to get this to work?

Thanks

**Modified gridsome.config.js** file:

```
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");  // ADDED THIS LINE
const tailwind = require("tailwindcss");
const purgecss = require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss");

const postcssPlugins = [tailwind(), autoprefixer()]; // ADDED `autoprefixer()` to postcssPlugins array

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") postcssPlugins.push(purgecss());

module.exports = {
  siteName: "Gridsome",
  plugins: [],
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: postcssPlugins
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is working -- I was just checking the wrong class.  It doesn't add prfixies for `display: flex` (since, I understand, all major browsers support `display: flex;`).

So I tried the `appearance-none` class (which sets `appearance: none;`).  And sure enough, it added the prefixes.

A special thanks, btw, to earthboundkid on reddit who came up with the answer:  https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/dy28wg/getting_autoprefixer_to_work_with_tailwindcss_and/f7y3agc?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x